# Java: How to search for a char variable in a string?

Tags: java, char, indexof

I need to find the position of char values that are derived from the user's input. But the indexOf method does not seem to work when I don't provide exact characters to look for. But since the char values are derived from the user's input, I cannot put in exact values. Any way to use indexOf the way I need to?

```
public class pg2a {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        String host;
        System.out
                .println("Please enter your sequence (any length, any characters):");
        host = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Now enter a 3 character sequence:");
        String candidate;
        candidate = keyboard.nextLine();

        int length = candidate.length();
        char a = candidate.charAt(0);
        char b = candidate.charAt(1);
        char c = candidate.charAt(2);
        int i = candidate.indexOf(a);
        int j = candidate.indexOf(b);
        int k = candidate.indexOf(c);

        if (length == 3) {
            if (i == -1)
                System.out
                        .println("The 3 character sequence you entered is not a subsequence of your sequence.");
            else
                System.out.println("Let's go!");
        } else {
            System.out
                    .println("The sequence you entered is not a 3 character sequence.");
        }
    }
}
```

`

Comment: I'd print `host` and `candidate` just to check they contained what I expected. Also you are looking for the chars in candiate, not host, so the whole exercise is a bit pointless.

Comment: You have to include j and k into your comparison

Comment: can you give us a test case?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the replies! But it seems was just a silly mistake on my part... I used the wrong string for the indexOf method. It should have been int i = host.indexOf(a) instead of candidate.indexOf(a) and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have should trivially set i to 0, j to 1, and c to 2 (assuming they're all different characters). You say "give me the index of the first character", then the second and third. I believe you meant to do `host.indexOf(a)`, etc.

However, there is a more trivial way of doing what you want, which is just to use `host.indexOf(candidate)`, which should return > -1 if candidate is in host.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your problem correctly the lines:

```
int i = candidate.indexOf(a);
int j = candidate.indexOf(b);
int k = candidate.indexOf(c);
```

should be

```
int i = host.indexOf(a);
int j = host.indexOf(b);
int k = host.indexOf(c);
```

you want to find whether a is in host. a will always be in candidate. Also you're only checking for if a is in the sequence, not b and c

Comment: Yes, a will always be in candidate, but the program will ultimately determine if candidate is a substring of the host and this is just a part of the whole program.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is only to check whether `host` contains `candidate` or not then may be you can think of using `contains` method.

```
boolean isSubstring = host.contains(candidate);
```

If you need an index where `candidate` starts, then following should server the purpose.

```
int startIndex = host.indexOf(candidate);
```

Comment: Yup contains would have worked as well but the program needs to ultimately display the index of the 3 different characters that make up candidate in host, so I figured indexOf was required instead.